# Magento2: Could not save product "330664" with position 0 to category 3567

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

When I save a product after unassigning all categories from the product. I am getting the error `Could not save product "330664" with position 0 to category 3567`

I have checked the log and I can see the same thing in exception.log. I found that the error is coming from the below function
from

> Vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteByIds($categoryId, $sku)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

        $productID = $product->getId();
        if (!isset($productPositions[$productID])) {
            throw new InputException(__('Category does not contain specified product'));
        }
        $backupPosition = $productPositions[$productID];
        unset($productPositions[$productID]);

        $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
        try {
            $category->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __(
                    'Could not save product "%product" with position %position to category %category',
                    [
                        "product" => $product->getId(),
                        "position" => $backupPosition,
                        "category" => $category->getId()
                    ]
                ),
                $e
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But not able to find actual cause to throw it. does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: I think this is the same issue here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8970

Comment: @kul any solution for that?

Comment: This issue may occur with a duplicate product. I solved this issue using the follwing way. Set product "Visibility" to "Not Visible Individually" and then remove the category and save it. After the category is removed and the product is saved, you can set the "Visibility" back to its original value. I hope it will help others. Yes it did, thanks ...

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and you can find the exact issue by printing actual error from exception.

Temporary replace "deleteByIds" function with following code.

```
public function deleteByIds($categoryId, $sku)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

    $productID = $product->getId();
    if (!isset($productPositions[$productID])) {
        throw new InputException(__('Category does not contain specified product'));
    }
    $backupPosition = $productPositions[$productID];
    unset($productPositions[$productID]);

    $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __(
                'Could not save product "%product" with position %position to category %category',
                [
                    "product" => $product->getId(),
                    "position" => $backupPosition,
                    "category" => $category->getId()
                ]
            ),
            $e
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

After changing this, actual error will print and you will get idea what's the exact problem is.

Comment: hi, Nitin, is this the fix?

Comment: In my case it's fixed.

Comment: In My case it gives error:  Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 52

Comment: @NitinVala how to fix this?

Comment: @Divyesh, Magento by default throwing the exception which not providing the real error information.So, You temporarily need to change the code as I explained above to get the real error.

Comment: @NitinVala I resolved this error. its not by default its because of multiple entries of url rewite entry ...i delete all product url and regenerate with third party module ..so i fix it

Comment: @Divyesh Greate to hear that you fix it. whenever magento through this error it's always a different error then we thought and in most of the case it's because of URL rewrite. I just provided here the work around to found that exact error. above code is not solution.

Answer (score 7):

This issue may occur with a duplicate product.

I solved this issue using the following way.

Set product "Visibility" to "Not Visible Individually" and then remove the category and save it. After the category is removed and the product is saved, you can set the "Visibility" back to its original value.

I hope it will help others.

Comment: your solution is really appreciable bro.... thanks for the solution

Comment: Happy to hear it work for you :)

Comment: Thanks bro!  Saved me lots of time

Comment: Welcome @JoshuaBarnes You can make it as useful if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue and its working with that,
In my case its solved when i was set no from admin configuration under Google api "Enable Content Experiments"

Configuration => Sales => Google API => Enable Content Experiments 
set no and save.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I put the erorr message within the returned string

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php*

```
public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface $productLink)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($productLink->getCategoryId());
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($productLink->getSku());
    $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $productPositions[$product->getId()] = $productLink->getPosition();
    $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __(
                'Could not save product "%1" with position %2 to category %3 : error %4',
                $product->getId(),
                $productLink->getPosition(),
                $category->getId(),
                $e->getMessage()
            ),
            $e
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
public function deleteByIds($categoryId, $sku)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

    $productID = $product->getId();
    if (!isset($productPositions[$productID])) {
        throw new InputException(__("The category doesn't contain the specified product."));
    }
    $backupPosition = $productPositions[$productID];
    unset($productPositions[$productID]);

    $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __(
                'Could not save product "%product" with position %position to category %category : %error',
                [
                    "product" => $product->getId(),
                    "position" => $backupPosition,
                    "category" => $category->getId(),
                    "error" => $e->getMessage()
                ]
            ),
            $e
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

The error was about unique integrity in the database.

And sure enough there were duplicate category IDs in an array I was providing for linking products to categories

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagementInterface
) {
    $this->categoryLinkManagementInterface = $categoryLinkManagementInterface;
}

/**
 * Assign product to category
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @param array $categoryIds
 * @return void
 */
public function assignProductToCategory($product, $categoryIds = [])
{
    if(!empty($categoryIds)) {
        $this->categoryLinkManagementInterface->assignProductToCategories(
            $product->getSku(),
            $categoryIds
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be related to trying to assign the product to the same category within the same command.

Say you have an array of Category ID's as follows:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,1);    
$linkManagement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
$linkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
                                $product['sku']),
                                $array 
                            );
```

This would give you the error once it tries to assign the second request for category 1.

Comment: This is a repeat of the issue I highlighted in my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
If product has duplicated Url: 
Edit product -> Search Engine Optimization -> URL Key -> [OTHER URL] with 'Create Permanent Redirect for old URL' unchecked -> Save
```

```
If Mysql has gone away(edit my.ini):
max_allowed_packet = 4000M
```

Answer (score -4):

**100% solution Working:**

Delete all Product Url in mysql:

```
delete from url_rewrite where entity_type = 'product';
```

**Regenerate this url :**
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: This is not a good approach because if there are custom rewrites it will also permanently delete those as well. Can cause many unexpected consequences.

Comment: This will destroy your SEO