# “Could not save product ”5648“ with position 1 to category 6”

Tags: product, admin, category, magento2.2.6

When I tried to remove the category from the product edit page the following error is getting displayed.

I am saving the product manually via admin end.....

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem you can modify core to help see more meaningful error https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272647/70343

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/97d5dcc7fbea21a870a17062e0d1e7d2ca1515ea)

if you have old magento version

Comment: I have already tried this ... but no luck...