# removing categorty in product page is giving error

Tags: magento2, product, category, indexing

We are facing issues - https://prnt.sc/mgdybf why we are not able to remove the Deal and Pre Owned category.

---

> Could not save product "26652" with position 0 to category 435

---

What is this error message about? How to solve this issue?

Regards 
Rachna

Comment: Or https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213541/magento2-could-not-save-product-330664-with-position-0-to-category-3567/272647#272647

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Some people have faced this issue already and have a solution. Check these posts

[Magento2: Could not save product "330664" with position 0 to category 3567](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213541/magento2-could-not-save-product-330664-with-position-0-to-category-3567?rq=1)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8970

The error is from the **CategoryLinkRepository** File from *module-catalog* which handles the save functionality. Check your exception log for more details, which tells you exactly why you couldn't save the product. Hope am pointing you to the right direction. Check also **deleteByIds** method, it can be the potential cause of this issue.

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteByIds($categoryId, $sku)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

        $productID = $product->getId();
        if (!isset($productPositions[$productID])) {
            throw new InputException(__('Category does not contain specified product'));
        }
        $backupPosition = $productPositions[$productID];
        unset($productPositions[$productID]);

        $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
        try {
            $category->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __(
                    'Could not save product "%product" with position %position to category %category',
                    [
                        "product" => $product->getId(),
                        "position" => $backupPosition,
                        "category" => $category->getId()
                    ]
                ),
                $e
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

> magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository.php

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface $productLink)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($productLink->getCategoryId());
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($productLink->getSku());
        $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();
        $productPositions[$product->getId()] = $productLink->getPosition();
        $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
        try {
            $category->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __(
                    'Could not save product "%1" with position %2 to category %3',
                    $product->getId(),
                    $productLink->getPosition(),
                    $category->getId()
                ),
                $e
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```