# Magento 2.2.4: Could not save product "3395" with position 1 to category 1882

Tags: magento2, category-products, magento2.2.4, save

I am using Magento 2.2.4. Assigned a product to two categories. One of the categories is a child of the other. Following error is thrown while saving the parent category after removing the product association from it.

> Could not save product "3395" with position 1 to category 1882

Can you please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: please provide more information.

Comment: Please check more info.: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260866/removing-categorty-in-product-page-is-giving-error